# How to get browser window height in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to write a re-size script in jquery that sets the div height to a percentage, so that the site stays responsive when I re-size the browser. To do this for the width: I use this script

```
function changeWidth() {
    var listWidth = (listContainer.width()/$(window).width())*100;

    listContainer.width(listWidth + '%');
};
```

This is my changeHeight script

```
function changeHeight() {
    var mapHeight = (mapContainer.height()/$(window).height())*100;

    mapContainer.height(mapHeight + '%');
}
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with height my `$(window).height()` is returning the entire height of the page (which in this case, is 16738). I thought `$(window).height()` returned the browser window height? Any idea what else I could try?

**Edit:**

`console.log($(window).height() + ' - ' + $(document).height());` is returning `16738 - 16738`

Comment: And if you try `.innerHeight()` ?

Comment: Why are you not using CSS to control the width of your elements?

Comment: @hungerstar `height` is the issue, not `width`.

Comment: @Vucko his first example is using JS to set a percentage width. Hence the  question in the comments.

Comment: It might be the issue with a missing !DOCTYPE however when I add one it screws up positioning of elements on my page

Comment: @hungerstar I am using percentages because jquery's resizable() function sets element's width in pixels, and I am setting it back to percentaces so that relative sizes are maintained when the browser window is resized

Comment: Seems a little unnecessary but okay. I'd like to know the context in which you're progmmatically setting the width for responsive design instead of a combo of percentages and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a DOCTYPE in my HTML statement.

I had `<html>` and changing it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and adding

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; /* for firefox */
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

to my css fixed the issue.

Comment: You must alse have the `<html>` tag - see [HTML5B's index page](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/index.html), which is THE way to start a web project.